# Can't start a new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to start a new rails app, I get this notification:

***"Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please Type 'rails' for help."***

I read that I may have to empty some directory because there may already be another rails app created. I'm not sure how to do this and start over.

Comment: What files are currently in that directory?

Comment: as per Bigg's question above, if you want to see what files you have in that directory, type ls ... it will show all files there.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd ~
cd ProjectsDir # <= Wherever you save your projects
rails new project
cd project
rails generate ...
```

Answer (score 1):

typing cd .. means going backwards in the directory you're in ...

for example, you're in this_directory, and it's on desktop ...

so, typing cd .. while in this_directory means that you're back on desktop directory now ...

as for the current directory that you're in, don't worry about it ...

just go backwards, and when outside of it, you can delete that directory as you wish, or leave it alone.

type "rails new name_of_app" to start a new rails project ...

and of course, type cd name_of_app to go into the directory of your new rails project.

let us know if you need further clarification ...

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ../
rails new i_am_in_new_directory
```